# Having trouble passing variable through Controller, into Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make an ajax request along with a variable in the url of the request.

The request is supposed to retrieve results for Recipes, which has a pivot table for Flavors.

The query should retrieve all Recipes with specified flavor. I am not able to pass the $flavorID variable into the query though. Getting an undefined error.

```
Route::get('/api/recipes/flavor/{flavorID}', function($flavorID){


    return App\Recipe::whereHas('flavors', function ($query) {

        $query->where('flavor_id', $flavorID);

    })->paginate(20);



});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$flavorID` does not exist in the scope of the function being passed to `whereHas`. Use the `use` keyword to include the variable in the scope of the function.

```
Route::get('/api/recipes/flavor/{flavorID}', function($flavorID){
    return App\Recipe::whereHas('flavors', function ($query) use ($flavorID) {
        $query->where('flavor_id', $flavorID);
    })->paginate(20);
});
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you have a sub-function, you need to pass variables into scope:

```
// http://example.com/api/recipies/flavor/vanilla
Route::get('/api/recipes/flavor/{flavorID}', function($flavorID){
    return App\Recipe::whereHas('flavors', function ($query) use($flavorID) {
        $query->where('flavor_id', $flavorID);
    })->paginate(20);;
});
```

Adding `use($flavorId)` allows `$flavorID` to be used within `function($query)`. If you omit it, then you get an `undefined` error as you're experiencing.